# Storing images as blob in DB or storing them in filesystem on server?

Tags: image, filesystems, blob, storage

Well I am trying to make a small social networking application and i will be storing images off-course. I have previously tried storing images using filesystem technique but this time i am thinking of trying the database way .But i am confused. Which way is better .Which one is faster . What are the advantages and disadvantages of both.
What technique do major social networking applications use? I'd really appreciate the advice. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have tried out storing image as blob for one of my projects. 
> I
>   havent worked on the filesystem storage implementation.

**Cons of blob:**

- Marginal increase in size of db.
- Slow retrieval rates.

**Pros:**

- Portable

Hope this reply helps
Cheers :)

Comment: Yeah fast retrieval is very important for me so the answer helps :)
Meaning of portable?

Comment: why is the retrieval slow btw?

Comment: @MuhammadOan portable is the easiness of transfer to a different enviorment,say you are moving your db to a different server.

Comment: retrieval becomes slow for large data sets. for small projects it doesnt matter.i myself have used blob storage for my project..

Comment: ahhhhhhhh hard choice . Anyways thnx sir :)

Comment: @SyedMuhammadOan - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay : Do avoid duplication of questions. Hope it helps more!